# How about make a home made VPN. Am short of money to renew my VPN

Tags: vpn, encryption, perl, ruby

Is it possible? For instance I create process that listen 80 and 443 port,
collect data, crypt it with special key inside. 
Then send it to server. Server decrypt data and check key, if key okay,
it send data further and wait for answer.
Get answer crypt it and send to client. Client decrypt data check key and only show result in browser (many ways how to do this).
And we have home made VPS. And notbody anymore can sniff our traffic.

What you think?
What technologies you would use to that?
How about prototype?
Maybe someone already try to do same.

Ha? Wait for your answer.

Dont count me crazy I have money to pay for VPS it just so curious to do it myself. And will raise my level of language learning.

I use, Perl, Ruby, Python. JS by the way too.

Thank you Guyz.

Comment: Disregard my previous comment, I misread your question. If you actually have a spare server, why not install proper VPN or proxy software on it?

Comment: That sounds like a lot of effort to recreate the wheel. Why not just use a free VPN like [SoftEther](https://www.softether.org/) or [Freelan](http://freelan.org/)? (I've never tried either of those and am not recommending them over others -- just giving examples.)

Comment: VPS is cheap if you don't need network bandwidth. Otherwise you pay extra or are throttled. And if you don't need much bandwidth, there are free VPNs.

Comment: It's not a bad question, but you could've done at least _some_ research yourself...

Comment: First rule of Cryptography (and its implementation): "NEVER ROLL YOUR OWN". Cryptographic standards require immense amounts of peer review and testing, so even the best cryptographers in the world don't just write their own. Additionally when using strong well vetted cryptography, the biggest vulnerability in it is the code USING the crypto algorithm to do its task, not the crypto itself. poorly written operational code or operational configuration (OPSec) will undermine the best theoretical algorithms we could muster every time.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a spare computer at home that can be on all the time then you can turn this into a VPN server.

If you have a router with DD-WRT (it may even have built-in VPN server capability - but not many SoHo ones do) or other custom firmwares then these can also be used as VPN servers that use OpenVPN.

A little research and trial and error on your behalf would have found many hundreds of results and guides on how to create a home VPN.

I would strongly discourage you from trying to create your own encryption mechanism - it's just not worth it and will inevitably be extremely insecure.

Use, for example, OpenVPN - it's tried and tested.

The only thing you will need to consider is whether you have a static or dyanmic public IP for your home Internet as you'll need to check a dynamic IP quite regularly to see if your modem has renewed this as it may be different and if you're away and the IP changes you'll not know what it might be so might not be able to connect in. Dynamic DNS services can help with this or you may have/be able to get a static IP from your ISP so you know it won't change.